# Swapper task on multiple CPU cores

Tags: linux

I have one query regarding swapper task (idle task) in Linux. I have a system having 16 CPU cores. Using taskstats, I could figure out that swapper task is running on core 0. 
I am under impression that every CPU core requires a swapper task to run when there are no other runnable tasks for that CPU. If its true then why swapper task showing to be running on cpu0 only and if its wrong then what rest of cpu cores does when there are no runnable tasks?

Looking forward to your help. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you care? I%t is the kernel's business!

Comment: I care because its useful in one of my project tool. I have 2 ways of knowing idle time of any CPU core. 1) Find out timings of swapper task running on each core through taskstats 2) Read /proc/stat
I have opted for first as taskstats is already implemented in my project and opting second would be an overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idle tasks job is, as you say, to run when there is nothing to else to run, so the CPU doesn't run out of instructions.

So that means that on a system with a single core the idle process makes sure that the CPU always has something to do, so it doesn't stop.

On a multi CPU/core system the same thing is true, however some CPU's allow for the system to put some of the cores to into idle mode to save power. In this case you only need to keep a single core alive, with the idle process, because then when the kernel is switched into that core, it can wake up more cores on demand.

*Please note that the above is a simplified version of the whole truth. Just trust the kernel to do the right thing, it usually knows what it's doing, and only want what's best for you :-)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
1) Is there a way to know for how long a particular core had been switched off? Does kernel dump such data somewhere for users to read?
2) As i would like to have detailed understanding of Kernel's handling of multicore system, Is there any links/reference you can suggest?

Comment: 1) I don't know. 2) What you want to know is very architecture, and even CPU specific. So I think the only place you'll find up to date information is in the kernel source.